# remove nested null or empty values from object

Tags: javascript

How can i clean empty nested objects value like this?
I need to return only the dRannge since it has value

```
const obj = {
 dRange: {daysBack: 10},
 tRange: {fromTime: {dateTime: ""}}
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to remove the tRange property from this object?

Comment: `delete obj.tRange` will remove the property. Now you will need to come up with the logic to find the empty values.

Comment: Yes. But assume i have similar large object with many properties and i need to check and iterate all object and remove empty values